# How to retrieve unique rows based on column value combinations?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `mytable` like below;

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═════╗
║ product ║ tag  ║ lot ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═════╣
║ 1111    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 1111    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 2222    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 3333    ║ 104  ║ 2   ║  
║ 4444    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 102  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║
║ 7777    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 101  ║ 1   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 102  ║ 3   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║ 
╚═════════╩══════╩═════╝
```

I have the input `101`,`102`. I want the output like;

```
2,5
3,5
```

which means, in the table, it will look for combinations `101,102`, and returns the **exact same combinations** with **different lot number**. Along with this, I want to avoid duplicate rows. Here `1111` and `5555` has same tags with same corresponding lot numbers to `tag`s, so I want only one row instead of 2 rows. Even though, `8888` has tags `101` and `102` with different `lot`s, it cannot be considered for listing , since it includes tag `103` in addition. Which means, I want products with exact `101, 102` combination. In short, I dont want products with any extra tags, and i dont want anything with missing tags.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "so I want to avoid duplicate rows. How can I do this?" - auto_increment.

Comment: Please provide some more examples on what results you want and what you don't want.

Comment: i think without duplicate check it should be something like this: `select product, tag, lot from mytable m where exist (select 1 from mytable m1 where m1.tag = '101') and exist (select 1 from mytable m2 where m2.tag = '102')` and than he need remove duplicates and product info and transform into one row for every product.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query returns duplicate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887053/mysql-query-returns-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Answer modified for updated question**

NOTE: query not tested

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lot ORDER BY lot ASC SEPARATOR ',') 
from mytable 
having count(*) = 2 
  and GROUP_CONCAT(tag ORDER BY tag ASC SEPARATOR ' ') = '101 102' 
group by product
```

**old answer**

you can use group by to achieve this.

```
select tag, product from mytable where tag in (101,102) group by tag, product
```

this may also be possible using distinct, but you have take a look into it. i cant remember if distinct is possible in multiple columns. I think this will work too...

```
select distinct tag, product from mytable where tag in (101,102)
```

Comment: can u make a sql fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

How about just a simple `SELECT` query with `IN` clause and `GROUP By` both?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE tag IN (101, 102)
GROUP BY tag, lot;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09bcc/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(firstTable.tag, " - ", firstTable.lot, secondTable.tag, " - ", secondTable.lot))
    (SELECT tag,lot FROM mytable WHERE tag = 101) AS firstTable INNER JOIN
    (SELECT tag,lot FROM mytable WHERE tag = 102) AS secondTable
     ON firstTable.product = secondTable.product
    WHERE firstTable.lot <> secondTable.lot
```

As I got from your question I think you need same **product** of given **tag** having diff **lot**

NOTE: I am not sure about CONCAT function as I have not practiced it.

Comment: I cant adopt `(SELECT tag,lot FROM mytable WHERE tag = 101)` since there will be lot more combinations coming and think will be difficult on the stage.

Comment: these (101 102) will be variables and if you have more combinations then just give some examples for that

Comment: Your combinations of tag will be of two or more?

Comment: I mean `(SELECT tag,lot FROM mytable WHERE tag = 101)` will repeat for every tags. I want to avoid that. I am looking for a more simpler code.

Comment: There can be n number of combinations

Comment: I think stored procedures will help you more in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one it avoids duplicate and group the tab and lot columns together. Try to modify to get required output

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(tag," - ",lot)) FROM mytable 
WHERE tag IN (101,102) GROUP BY product ;
```

Solution as per new update:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(m.lot) FROM mytable m
GROUP BY m.product HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(m.tag ORDER BY m.tag) = '101,102';
```

Output:

```
2,5
```

Refer: [DISTINCT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx), [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)

Reference: [MySQL query returns duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34887135/2127125)

Comment: you have the exact solution for your problem in the link provided by @CodeGodie

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ question is also yours only. Any way you got the solution and me also learnt from that :-)