# MySQL query returns unwanted rows on fetching rows based on specific tag combinations

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I run PHP+MySQL in my Windows 8 PC. I have a table `mytable` like below;

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═════╗
║ product ║ tag  ║ lot ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═════╣
║ 1111    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 1111    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 2222    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 3333    ║ 104  ║ 2   ║  
║ 4444    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 102  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║
║ 7777    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 101  ║ 1   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 102  ║ 3   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 9999    ║ 101  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 9999    ║ 102  ║ 8   ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═════╝
```

I have the input `101`,`102`. I want the output like;

```
2,5
6,8
```

The query will look for combinations `101,102`, and returns the **exact same combinations** with **different lot number**. Along with this, I want to avoid duplicate rows. Here `1111` and `5555` has same tags with same corresponding lot numbers to `tag`s (exact same combinations with same lots), so I want only one row instead of 2 rows. Even though, `8888` has tags `101` and `102` with different `lot`s, it cannot be considered for listing , since it includes tag `103` in addition. In short, I want products with exact `101, 102` combination, and I dont want products with any extra tags, and i dont want anything with missing tags.

I have a query like below;

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(m.lot) FROM mytable m
WHERE m.tag IN (101,102) 
AND (SELECT COUNT(m.product) FROM mytable m2 WHERE m.product = m2.product)>1
GROUP BY m.product;
```

which returns;

```
2,5
2
5,2
1,3
6,8
```

How can I fix this? Is there any better method to accomplish what I am looking for?

Here is the fiddle to start with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11d6

Comment: The input data in your sqlfiddle isn't the same as in the question. It has two `8888 101 1` rows.

Comment: @Mihai i deleted that question

Comment: @Barmar fixed that and included new fiddle link. But I was unable to include the query in that fiddle, seems like fiddle is down

Comment: Yeah, I keep getting errors when I try to run a query, too. This seems to happen often with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve unique rows based on column value combinations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871945/how-to-retrieve-unique-rows-based-on-column-value-combinations)

Comment: @Mihai I have included the query and fiddle here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query returns duplicate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887053/mysql-query-returns-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using simple join for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.lot, b.lot
FROM mytable a
    INNER JOIN mytable b ON b.product = a.product AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product WHERE tag NOT IN (a.tag, b.tag))
WHERE a.tag = 101 and b.tag = 102
```

Comment: But what if I have more than 2 combinations? say like `101,102,103` combination?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this does what you want:

```
select group_concat(lot order by lot)
from mytable
group by product
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = '101,102';
```

This seems to return the results you want.  This would be a bit more efficient with a `where` clause:

```
select group_concat(lot order by lot)
from mytable
where tag in ('101', '102')
group by product
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = '101,102';
```

Comment: Thanks. The first query returns 3 rows `2,5`, `2,5`, `6,8`, here `2,5` combination repeats. The second query returns 5 rows `2,5`, `2,5`, `2,5`, `1,3`, `6,8`. What I want is 2 rows, `2,5` and `6,8.

Comment: You would just use `select distinct` in the queries rather than `select`.

Answer (score 0):

By doing group by product, and HAVING clause is explicitly looking for ONLY those products that have both the 101 and 102 and NO OTHER.  Once each product is qualified, it's concatenated lots are included.  If another has same concatenation, only one set will be returned.  Because of your duplicate entries of the same tag 101 within a product, I only care if one IS found regardless of it being duplicated hence the MAX() for 101 and 102 both = 1 respectively.

```
select DISTINCT
      group_concat( DISTINCT m.lot ORDER BY m.lot ASC SEPARATOR ','  )
   from
      myTable m
   group by
      m.product
   having
          MAX( case when m.tag = '101' then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
      AND MAX( case when m.tag = '102' then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
      AND sum( case when m.tag in ( '101', '102' ) then 0 else 1 end ) = 0;
```

And if you want to see how each individual product compares, remove the HAVING clause to see their respective values

```
select 
      m.product,
      group_concat( DISTINCT m.lot ORDER BY m.lot ASC SEPARATOR ','  ),
      sum( case when m.tag in ( '101', '102' ) then 1 else 0 end ) as WantTags,
      sum( case when m.tag in ( '101', '102' ) then 0 else 1 end ) as OtherTags
   from
      myTable m
   group by
      m.product
```

I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cf251/2) instance for you.  Few minor things.  I changed the column names to "tag1", "lot1".

```
select DISTINCT
      group_concat( DISTINCT m.lot1 ORDER BY m.lot1 ASC SEPARATOR ','  )
   from
      myTableXYZ m
   group by
      m.product
   having
          MAX( case when m.tag1 = 101 then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
      AND MAX( case when m.tag1 = 102 then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
      AND sum( case when m.tag1 in ( 101, 102 ) then 0 else 1 end ) = 0;
```

So my query runs against your SQLFiddle and has the results

```
2,5
1,3,5
6,8
```

Comment: Thanks. So how can I achieve my result? What might be the query for that? How can I do this?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, the first query SHOULD give what you need, the second is to show the results on a per-product basis to confirm what MySQL is pulling and with the extra columns of WANT vs OTHER tags, you can see what should / not be done.

Comment: Can you post the query here or show me a fiddle please

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, updated SQL Fiddle.  Also note of column change for reserved word conflict consideration.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, you are only expecting 2 entries and not the product with  duplicate entry of lot 1 (as you had of 1,3,1, but uniquely would create 1,3)?  Should that be included or excluded.  If EXCLUDED, change the MAX() back to SUM()

Comment: I did a mistake in my fiddle, its 1,3,5 not 1,3,1. See my question and fiddle.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, ran against yours, revised my answer at the end for its results.  Or are you expecting DISTINCT 101, 102 tags so the entry for product 8888 shows as 1,3 and 3,5 instead of 1,3,5?

Comment: I just want to output `2,5` and `6,8` when user gives input `101,102` combination. I dont want 7777 and 8888 coz it contains extra tags. Here, valid products are 1111,5555, and 9999. We just want only one among 1111 and 2222 since their tag and lot combinations are same.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, then 8888 would be removed IF you changed the MAX() calls to SUM() in the having clause.   But your 8888 entry only HAS tags 101 and 102, but it has TWO INSTANCES of tag 101, but a different LOT.  If you could explain what it is you are really trying to get out of this in simple English explanation vs the query, that MIGHT help better.