# MySQL query returns duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table `mytable` like below;

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═════╗
║ product ║ tag  ║ lot ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═════╣
║ 1111    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 1111    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 2222    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 3333    ║ 104  ║ 2   ║  
║ 4444    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 102  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║
║ 7777    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 101  ║ 1   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 102  ║ 3   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 9999    ║ 101  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 9999    ║ 102  ║ 8   ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═════╝
```

I have the input `101`,`102`. I want the output like;

```
2,5
6,8
```

I have a query like;

```
select group_concat(lot order by lot)
from `mytable`
group by product
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = '101,102';
```

It returns;

```
2,5
2,5
6,8
```

Instead of two `2,5`, I want just one, avoiding duplicate rows. How can I do this?

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a78bb/1/0

Comment: try `select distinct group_concat(lot order by lot)`

Comment: TIL that SQLFiddle is a Thing.  Awesome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query returns unwanted rows on fetching rows based on specific tag combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885425/mysql-query-returns-unwanted-rows-on-fetching-rows-based-on-specific-tag-combina)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos it worked. Please post it as answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `distinct` then

```
select distinct group_concat(lot order by lot)
from `mytable`
group by product
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = '101,102';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just use `DISTINCT` to Eliminate Duplicates

```
select DISTINCT group_concat(lot order by lot)
from `mytable`
group by product
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = '101,102';
```