# Why this MySQL query returns result only if input is in a particular order?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table `mytable` like below;

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═════╗
║ product ║ tag  ║ lot ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═════╣
║ 1111    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 1111    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 2222    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 3333    ║ 104  ║ 2   ║  
║ 4444    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 5555    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 102  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 6666    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║
║ 7777    ║ 101  ║ 2   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 102  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 7777    ║ 103  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 101  ║ 1   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 102  ║ 3   ║ 
║ 8888    ║ 103  ║ 5   ║ 
║ 9999    ║ 101  ║ 6   ║ 
║ 9999    ║ 102  ║ 8   ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═════╝
```

I have a query like;

```
select distinct group_concat(lot order by lot)
from `mytable`
group by product
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = '101,102';
```

Which is suppose to give me an output like;

```
2,5
6,8
```

The query will look for combinations `101,102`, and returns the **exact same combinations** with **different lot number**. Along with this, I want to avoid duplicate rows. Here `1111` and `5555` has same tags with same corresponding lot numbers to `tag`s (exact same combinations with same lots), so I want only one row instead of 2 rows. Even though, `8888` has tags `101` and `102` with different `lot`s, it cannot be considered for listing , since it includes tag `103` in addition. In short, I want products with exact `101, 102` combination, and I dont want products with any extra tags, and i dont want anything with missing tags.

The code works fine. But there is a problem. If i give input `101,102`, the query works fine. But if I give `102,101` as input, then I get no rows, but I want to get the exact result as in the previous condition, ignoring the order in which the tag numbers are given. Also, sometimes there can be more than two numbers as input like `101,102,103`, `101,102,103,104` etc.

How can i do this? Here is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a78bb/11/0

Comment: I feel like we've covered this one before.

Comment: As you have generated group_concat() which is grouping the records you want but it is just like string. In you example when you are passing value 101,102 your query does group_concat() and return result of 101,102 and compare. But when you are passing data 102,101 the query same does the group_concat() of 101,102 and compare it with 102,101 so as this is string, you can not get the proper result.

Comment: you are explicitely ordering the tags before concatenating them to a string and then comparing the strings, so the value you compare with has to be ordered as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve unique rows based on column value combinations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871945/how-to-retrieve-unique-rows-based-on-column-value-combinations)

Answer (score 0):

If you like also a PHP solution.... a  possible solution is order the combition via php and formatting the value in a sequence of value in string ..

```
$tmp = explode(',', '101,102,103,104');
sort($tmp);
$myComb = implode(',',$tmp);

$sql="select distinct group_concat(lot order by lot)
from `mytable`
having group_concat(tag order by tag) = " . myComb . " ; ";
```

Comment: If you see DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query, at the very least alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: That's making it worse :-(

Comment: @Strawberry yes.. thanks  i have just copied the query by OP i was looking for ordering solution..anyway   i have upate then answer..

Comment: @Strawberry the query however worl correctly with group by ..,. could be is what  the OP need.. .. This don't change the senso of my suggestion..that is if you compare an ordered result you nedd an ordered matching value..

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the OP doesn't really know what they need. When they figure that out, I think we might be able to provide a more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I would tend to use a combination of php and mysql, I thought I would have a play and see if I could come up with a pure SQL version of this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(lot ORDER BY lot)
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IF(FIND_IN_SET(tag, '101,102'), tag, NULL)) = 1 + LENGTH('101,102') - LENGTH(REPLACE('101,102', ',', ''))
AND COUNT(tag) = 1 + LENGTH('101,102') - LENGTH(REPLACE('101,102', ',', ''));
```

This will not care which order the comma separated list of values is in. But is not going to be efficient!