# MySQL - Select new entries only for every day

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the new tasks assigned to employees per day. The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2405f)

An employee may cycle between say 4 tasks A,B,C & D. On 1st Jan, he may get assigned task 'A', on 2nd Jan he may get assigned task 'B', 5th Jan task 'C', 6th Jan task 'D' & say on Jan 14th he gets assigned task 'A' again. I'd like to see the date & the newly assigned task compared to the previous day with respect to any particular day.

The output of the SQL I need should show me only the new task he is assigned on a given day. The definition of new is with respect to the previous day or the last present entry if data is not present for a given date.

Here's how it should ideally look -
[image]

**UPDATED SQL**

[FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c00e2/4)

```
SELECT   task_date, 
         employee_name, 
         Group_concat(task_name) 
FROM     ( 
                         SELECT DISTINCT a.task_date, 
                                         a.employee_name, 
                                         CASE 
                                                         WHEN b.employee_name IS NOT NULL
                                                         AND             c.employee_name IS NULL THEN NULL
                                                         ELSE a.task_name
                                         END       AS task_name 
                         FROM            forgerock AS a 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN forgerock AS b 
                         ON              a.employee_name = b.employee_name = 'A'
                         AND             a.task_date >= '2015-01-02' 
                         AND             a.task_date <= '2015-01-04' 
                         AND             b.task_date >= '2015-01-02' 
                         AND             b.task_date <= '2015-01-04' 
                         AND             a.task_date - 1 = b.task_date
                         AND             a.region = b.region = 'USA' 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN forgerock AS c 
                         ON              a.employee_name = c.employee_name = 'A'
                         AND             a.task_date >= '2015-01-02' 
                         AND             a.task_date <= '2015-01-04' 
                         AND             c.task_date >= '2015-01-02' 
                         AND             c.task_date <= '2015-01-04' 
                         AND             a.task_date - 1 = c.task_date
                         AND             a.task_name <> c.task_name 
                         AND             a.region = b.region = 'USA' 
                         ORDER BY        a.task_date, 
                                         a.employee_name, 
                                         a.task_name) AS temp 
GROUP BY task_date, 
         employee_name
```

Comment: your data is messed up maybe, and you aren't showing what your output should be. If you expect someone to write it in this free write my code for me service you think SO is, at least show a table of expected results.

Comment: Utilizing as a free service is definitely not what I'm after mate. I take the point of showing a table. Sure, I'll do. I'd appreciate one being able to control the assumptions rather than translating it into harsh comments mate. Would appreciate that.

Comment: If you look at my answers, I am more than willing to spend time helping people. Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34919144). He went from really confusing questions to being one of the best askers. If you make it clear what you are after, people don't waste all their time.

Comment: I agree on the clarity part. With you there. Updated the question & the data in the fiddle too. I did try playing around but can't get the today to previous day comparison in the SQL.

Comment: Here [is a start](http://i.imgur.com/du0zBjw.jpg). I will send a friend over to see if he has time to figure it out from here.

Comment: Thank you Drew. Appreciate your help. Apologies about the confusion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select task_date,employee_name,GROUP_CONCAT(task_name) from(
select distinct a.task_date,a.employee_name
,case when b.employee_name is not null and c.employee_name is null
then null
else a.task_name end as task_name
from ForgeRock as a left outer join ForgeRock as b
on a.employee_name = b.employee_name and a.task_date-1 = b.task_date 
left outer join ForgeRock as c
on a.employee_name = c.employee_name and a.task_date-1 = c.task_date 
and a.task_name <> c.task_name
order by a.task_date,a.employee_name,a.task_name) as temp
group by task_date,employee_name
```

Adding Condition :

```
select task_date,employee_name,GROUP_CONCAT(task_name) from(
select distinct a.task_date,a.employee_name
,case when b.employee_name is not null and c.employee_name is null
then null
else a.task_name end as task_name
from ForgeRock as a left outer join ForgeRock as b
on a.employee_name = b.employee_name and a.task_date-1 = b.task_date and a.task_date between  '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-04' and b.task_date between  '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-04' 
left outer join ForgeRock as c
on a.employee_name = c.employee_name and a.task_date-1 = c.task_date and a.task_date between  '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-04' and c.task_date between  '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-04'
and a.task_name <> c.task_name
where a.region = 'USA'  and a.task_date between '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-04'
order by a.task_date,a.employee_name,a.task_name) as temp

group by task_date,employee_name
```

Comment: Hello - Thank you heaps for trying. Still isn't working :(

Comment: If the task is chenged, display it. Otherwise display null. Is it correct?

Comment: Hello - I've updated the question under "UPDATED SQL". I'm trying to add a date range, employee name & region filter. However, it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I guess I'm adding it in the wrong place. In case it's okay, would you be be able to take a look for me please? Given the amount of data I have, this query is not completing even after about 20 min :-) Hence, would like to apply filters & see the impact

Comment: You have some conditions to filter in join ,but it is an outer join, you need to add the same condition to where condition to do a filter. :)

Comment: If you expect 2015-01-02 result is null, change the range of between in join only. Like this : between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-04'.